# How can I identify the content-type after opening an HTTP connection?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, httpcontent

**I am opening an HTTP connection to a URL that I am generating within my program:**

```
String url = INPUT_URL;
HttpURLConnection connection;
while (true)
{
    connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
    switch (connection.getResponseCode()/100)
    {
    case 3:
        url = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
        break;
    case 4:
    case 5:
        // Report some error
        return;
    }
}
```

**Now, in `case 2` I want to identify the content-type. For example:**

- When connecting to http://www.google.com, the content-type is Text.
- When connecting to http://www.google.com/favicon.ico, the content-type is Image.

**I cannot use the URL structure in order to determine that. For example:**

- When connecting to http://www.advertising.com/favicon.ico, the response-code is 200, but the content-type is Text (the content itself is "The requested file favicon.ico was not found.").

**I know how to read the content using an `InputStream` object, but:**

1. I wish to avoid fetching the content itself if possible.
2. I don't see how it can help me determine the content-type.

**Any ideas would be highly appreciated... thanks.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `getContentType`:

> public String getContentType ()
>   Added in API level 1
>
> Returns the MIME-type of the content specified by the response header field content-type or null if type is unknown.

Comment: Question: what string would I get for an `ico` resource?

Comment: The registered mime type is `image/vnd.microsoft.icon` see [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/image/vnd.microsoft.icon)

Comment: I get `null` content-type for http://cdn0.sbnation.com/uploads/hub/favicon/247/favicon-0666b2d5.ico, although I clearly see an 'ico' when I connect to this URL through Firefox. Would you know how to explain this? Thanks

Comment: The server does not set a `content-type` header in the response for this URL.

Comment: So is this essentially a server "bug" which is not likely to happen in most servers?

Comment: BTW, for `ico` I see that there is an additional type on top of what you already mentioned a few comments above: image/x-icon